# Update or insert without unique or primary key

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to update a table, but I get this exception:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'IF exists (SELECT * FROM `indicadores_val` WHERE `indv_val` = ''
>   AND `ind_id` = ' at line 1

The query I am using is

```
IF exists 
    (SELECT * 
       FROM `indicadores_val` 
      WHERE `indv_val` = '' AND `ind_id` = 11) 
THEN
    UPDATE indicadores_val 
       SET ind_valr11 = '34',ind_valr12 = '54' 
     WHERE `indv_val` = ''   AND `ind_id` =11 
ELSE
    INSERT INTO `indicadores_val` (ind_id,ind_valr11,ind_valr12)   
    VALUES (11,60,60)
```

this is my schema

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `indicadores_val` (
  `indv_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ind_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `indv_val` text NOT NULL,
  `ind_fun` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ind_valr11` text NOT NULL,
  `ind_valr12` text NOT NULL,
  `ind_valr21` text NOT NULL,
  `ind_valr22` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`indv_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=41 ;
```

Comment: No `WHERE` clause on an `UPDATE`? What could *possibly* go wrong?

Comment: if you can't have unique/primary keys, then go grab a clue bat and beat some intelligence into the idjit who dropped that requirement onto the codebase.

Comment: Step 1 - run the subquery.

Comment: _i can't have unique or primary keys_ - yes you can. Don't be ridiculous.

Comment: Control structures like `IF/ELSE` are only valid inside MySQL stored procedures, functions, and triggers.  You cannot use them in an arbitrary query, and that's the source of your syntax error.

Comment: yes, i have one! indv_id

Comment: Sadly, that is an award-winningly awful schema. What do those columns even mean? Why are they `TEXT`? Why are you using `latin1` in 2014, *especially* with data that's not strictly English? No indexes? No keys? This is a whole world of hurt. I really hope you can refactor this into something more sensible.

Comment: whoever designed that needs to read up on normalization too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using unique constraints then you'll need to implement the conditional logic in a script. You could do so in the scripting language of your choice, or you could use a MySQL stored procedure.

The stored procedure would look something like this:

```
delimiter $$

drop procedure if exists sp_inicadores_val_upsert $$

create procedure sp_inicadores_val_upsert (p_ind_id int,p_ind_valr11 int,p_ind_valr12 int) 
begin
  declare v_row_exists tinyint default 0;

  select count(*)
  into v_row_exists
  from 
  (
    select null 
    from `indicadores_val` 
    where `indv_val` = '' 
      and `ind_id` = p_ind_id 
    limit 1
  ) sub_query;

  if v_row_exists 
  then 
  THEN
    UPDATE indicadores_val 
    SET ind_valr11 = p_ind_valr11,
      ind_valr12 = p_ind_valr12 
    WHERE `indv_val` = ''   
      AND `ind_id` = p_ind_id;
  else 
    INSERT INTO `indicadores_val` (ind_id,ind_valr11,ind_valr12)   
    VALUES (p_ind_id,p_ind_valr11,p_ind_valr12);
  end if;

end $$

delimiter ;
```

Comment: This is one of those "If stored procedures aren't solving your problem, you're probably not using enough of them" scenarios, isn't it? This is a clever solution to an otherwise incurably bad schema, but it's just fossilizing the bad schema in ways that'll make it even harder to unwind.

Comment: @tadman I disagree. The essence of the question is: "How to conditionally do an update or insert based on the existence of a specific row?". The answer is that you can't use `IF` like that in MySQL, it either needs to be in the client code or in a stored proc. Since the OP doesn't say what client language is used I thought it was easier to give the example as a stored proc.

Comment: Your solution is arguably the best in absence of other knowledge, but like you suggest, application code is the better solution here.

Comment: i'm using php, i solve my problem in this way

function upsert($find,$insert,$update) {  


        $consuloff = new conexion("");
        $consuloff ->conectarBD();

        $consuloff->consultarBD($find);

        if($regis=$consuloff->obtenerResultado())
        {
            $consuloff->consultarBD($update); 
        }
        else
        {
          $consuloff->consultarBD($insert);  
        }
      }

Answer (score 2):

The most likely reason is that this code is not inside a stored procedure or function.  Read about the `if` statement [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html).

I suspect you want someting like this:

```
INSERT INTO `indicadores_val`(ind_id, ind_valr11, ind_valr12)
    values ( 11, 60, 60 )
    on duplicate key update ind_valr11 = 34, ind_valr12 = 54;
```

I am not sure how the condition on the `invv_val` gets applied.  Do you really want the presence of a value in that field to prevent an update?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use END IF at the end of the query
see the documentation of IF syntax http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
INSERT INTO `indicadores_val` (ind_id,ind_valr11,ind_valr12)   
    VALUES (11,60,60)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ind_id = VALUES(ind_id), ind_valr11 = VALUES(ind_valr11), ind_valr12 = VALUES(ind_valr11)
```